# Wallet Question - Hardware - Software

Tags: mining, wallets

thx for the post.
I had a few questions.
When running this command:

```
geth account new
```

Does this create a wallet?

What if I have a hardware wallet and do not want to use a software wallet, is it possible?

Also after running `C:\> geth --rpc`
How long do I have to wait?  It seems I have been waiting over 10 hours and its still processing something.  Is this normal?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

when you do 
geth account new

this creates a new wallet address and it does prompt you to save it in a secure place.
geth is a wallet in itself based on command line.

when you run it to sync the blockchain it does take along time because it is getting all the blocks on the network.
i would advise you to check your hard drive as it may be full and the sync process will stop.